# [play-framework : 2.1.2-java : thread pool configuration and AsyncResult

Tags: playframework-2.1

We have a typical web-service which serves JSON data read from a remote database. I was trying out returning Result and AsyncResult, each with the following configuration:

```
play {
   akka {
     event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
     loglevel = WARNING
     actor {
       default-dispatcher = {
         fork-join-executor {
           parallelism-factor = 1.0
           parallelism-max = 1
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

and one with

```
   parallelism-factor = 1.0
   parallelism-max = 5
```

Following are observations where the time taken to complete 500 requests is given (average of 5 readings):

```
1. parallelism-max=1 and parallelism-factor=1.0
   Result :
   Completion time = 291662 ms.
   AsyncResult:
   Completion time = 55601 ms

2. parallelism-max=5 and parallelism-factor=1.0
   Result :
   Completion time = 46419 ms.
   AsyncResult:
   Completion time = 46977 ms
```

We can see that with parallelism-max=1, AsyncResult clearly takes very less time compare to Result. However, with parallelism-max=5, Result and AsyncResult give very similar timings.
Shouldn't the time required become less as the number of threads increases, for AsyncResult also ?
Requesting for help to understand the reasons behind this observation.

Comment: How much time does the database access take?

Comment: I hadn't measured it before. I tried measuring it individually and takes appx 600 ms average (ranges from 300+ms to 1200+ms) for one request.

Comment: Per request is not meaningful, how much time is spent waiting for the DB in your test run?

Comment: @Viktor : Thanks for the reply !
I have found that the DB query method that retrieves the DB results takes almost same time in both cases (this is measured with just the difference in system time milliseconds before and after the method call).
Is there any specific tool which can be used to measure specific timings like you have mentioned (time spent waiting for the DB). Requesting to please shed some light on this. 
Also, if the time required in both the cases is similar, will it affect the reasons for my original question ?
Thanks.

Comment: Since your database API is most likely blocking, there's nothing the caller-thread can do until it responds.

Comment: Okay. Yes the database API is blocking. Is it because of this that AsyncResult and Result give similar timings for multiple threads ? Also, would it be the case that after a certain number of requests the timings will again be skewed ? Thanks

Comment: It's easy to verify by instead of calling the database you instead schedule a Future to be completed after a random interval between 300 and 1200ms—and have it being completed with a dummy value you can use for testing.